# Validate yaml path in Ansible Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have Cloudformation template in yaml format.
The template is rendered by Ansible Jinja2.

I need to find a way to add validation of some elements inside the template. Something like this ("if" statement is a pseudo code of what I want to get):

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentType:
    Default: {{profile}}

    Mappings:
        Environments:
            dev:
                DbSnapshotArn: ""
            test:
                DbSnapshotArn: "AAA"

           Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
            Properties:
             {% if Mappings.Environments.{{profile}}.DbInstanceClass %}
                    DBSnapshotIdentifier: !FindInMap [Environments, !Ref 'EnvironmentType', DbSnapshotArn]
            {% endif %}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not if `Mappings.Environments.{{profile}}.DbInstanceClass` references something inside the template.

But if you define a variable like this:

```
Mappings:
  Environments:
    Dev:
      DbInstanceClass: "..."
```

And another variable that contains the value of `profile`, then inside your template you can create an `if` statement like this:

```
{% if Mappings.Environments[profile].DbInstanceClass is defined %}
...
{% endif %}
```

See also:

- [Jinja2 Tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#tests)

Comment: The main issue here is not accessing another variable. Ansible returns error "fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'Mappings' is undefined"}" When Ansible renders the template it accesses "Mappings" as Ansible variable. I need to find a way to validate YAML path.